# ¿Cómo reflejar mis cambios de una hoja de estilo css en Django y Apache?

Tags: python, django, apache

Primero plantearé todo lo que hice y luego al final el problema.

Logré usar una hoja de estilo personal en el proyecto de la siguiente forma, que encontré en internet. 
Primero cree una carpeta llamada **static** en la raiz de la aplicación Django, en esta cree una carpeta llamada **css**, y dentro de esta puse mi hoja de estilo **style.css**

Luego en la plantilla **index.html** que es la que usará la hoja de estilo, al principio antes que todo escribí:

**{% load static %}**

Y entonces en el encabezado cargué la hoja de estilo así:
**<
link rel="stylesheet" 
href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">**

Para que pudiera cargar la página en la configuración de Apache puse:

Alias /static/ "/posts/static/"

<
Directory "/posts/static">
Require all granted

<
/Directory>

Hasta aquí todo bien. Funcionó tanto con el servidor Apache como con el servidor que trae Django.

El problema está que una vez que el sitio ha cargado todo bien, y voy al editor y hago cambios en la hoja de estilo, ya no se reflejan los cambios en el sitio montado en Apache, puedo dejar la hoja de estilo en blanco, guardar los cambios, reiniciar el servidor Apache, parar el servidor, reiniciarlo, cerrar el editor, abrirlo comprobar que la hoja de estilo sigue en blanco, y nada, no se reflejan los cambios en la página. Cierro el navegador, lo abro de nuevo, voy al sitio y nada. Contra toda lógica (aparentemente), con la hoja de estilo en blanco, sigue el sitio mostrando lo que reflejaba la hoja de estilo inicial. Ya lo único que me falta es reiniciar la máquina.

Y es la única hoja de estilo que hay en el proyecto, quizás se pudiera pensar que estoy transformando otra y no la que usa la aplicación. Pues es la única no hay otra.

Eso sólo pasa con Apache pues con el servidor que trae Django no, ahí funciona bien, todo lo que cambio en la hoja de estilo se refleja en el sitio con este servidor, eso prueba de que es la hoja de estilo correcta, y que parece es el servidor Apache.

¿Es posible que el servidor cree algún archivo temporal de la hoja de estilo inicialmente y luego ya no vaya a la original? ¿Debo agregar otra configuración a Apache?

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Probaste utilizando ctrl + f5 para reiniciar el cache?

Comment: Pues se resolvió al reiniciar la laptop. Hacía más de una semana no la apagaba y había instalado varias cosas, nada que ver con apache pero bueno!! Ya todo volvió a la normalidad.

Comment: Para la proxima te recomiendo usar "ctrl + f5", lo que hace es borrar la cache del navegador... Si! El navegador guarda archivos temporales con el css para cargar mas rapido las paginas ya visitadas!

Comment: Gracias Patrick, siempre se aprende algo nuevo no había visto tu respuesta de ctrl + F5.

Comment: Por cierto ya esta pregunta está fuera del tema. Este sitio (Stack Overflow) me está saliendo diferente, por los lados veo como un mosaico de bastante imagenes que dice stack overflow y un unicornio partido a la mitad con la parte de alante en el lado izquierdo y la parte de atrás en el lado derecho, y el cursor cuando lo muevo suelta estrellistas de colores. ¿Es normal eso?¿Cambiaron el tema del sitio? Porque no he cambiado nada sin querer, no he elegido otro tema ni nada parecido en la configuración.

Comment: @YordanisCobasLobaina si quieres desactivar el efecto solo tienes que presionar el icono que parece un reloj que esta en el toolbar en la parte superior derecha

Comment: @YordanisCobasLobaina Sí, el cambio de estilo es una inocentada del 1 de Abril :-) Puedes volver al estilo normal (o de nuevo al estilo 90s) pinchando en el relojito arriba.

Comment: Sip caí en la inocentada pues llegué a pensar que era un tipo de virus. Gracias ya lo cambié, no me gusta me distrae de lo que estoy leyendo